# Printing a file does not work

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working with Python 2.7 in the PowerShell. I have this piece of code:

```
from sys import argv

script, filename = argv

target = open(filename, 'w')

#new content for file
line1 = raw_input("line1: ")
line2 = raw_input("line2: ")
line3 = raw_input("line3: ")

target.write(line1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line2)
target.write("\n")
target.write(line3)
target.write("\n")

#after that line the message occurs (see further down)
print target
target.close()
```

This is the message I get:

```
<open file 'test.txt', mode 'w' at 0x004C6230>
```

Why isn't it showing me my new content? When I open the file with a double click, the newly-added content is there. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're literally printing the file object, not the contents of the file. While it's not exactly the same, consider this analogy: If you `dir` the file in the command prompt, you don't expect to see the file contents, do you?

If you want to get the contents of the file, you have to `open` it and `read` it, just like if you want to change the contents of the file you had to `open` it and `write` it. So:

```
target.close()

source = open(filename, 'r')
print source.read()
source.close()
```

It's worth noting that you should use a `with` statement instead of manually `open` and `close` whenever possible.

---

> But why do I have to assign a new variable? It does not work if I try `print target.read`. Is it because of the w in one of my first lines?

The first problem is that `target.read` is the function object itself. To call a function and get a result, you need the parentheses: `target.read()`.

Next, yes, the `'w'` mode means that you can't read the file; you'd want to use `r+` or `w+` to fix that. (Read the docs on [`open`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#open) to see what all of the modes do.)

However, even fixing both those problems, you'd end up printing nothing, because after writing everything to `target`, you end up pointing at the end of the file, not the beginning, and `read()`will read everything from the end of the file on—which is nothing. So, you'd have to `target.seek(0)` to make that work.

So, if you *wanted* to reuse the same file object:

```
target = open(filename, 'w+')
# ... all the stuff to write the file
target.seek(0)
print target.read()
target.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. Worked perfectly without a loop! But why do I have to assign a new variable? It does not work if I try `print target.read`. Is it because of the `w` in one of my first lines?

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the file object, not the contents.

open with `"w+"` to read and write:

Then use `target.seek(0) # go back to start of the file`

`print target.readlines()  # print all contents`

The file pointer is at the end of the file, if you used `target.readlines()` or `target.read()` you would get no output, you need to `seek` back to the start of the file to read the contents.

It is better to use `with` to open your files as it closes them automatically.

```
with open(filename, 'w+') as target:
    #new content for file
    line1 = raw_input("line1: ")
    line2 = raw_input("line2: ")
    line3 = raw_input("line3: ")
     ....
```

Comment: You can't `readlines` a file in `w` mode. And, even if you could, this would print out a list.

Comment: @abarnert, I missed the w.

Comment: Probably better to use `r+` than `a+`. Otherwise, you're changing the meaning of his code so that instead of overwriting any existing file, it appends onto it. And you're also making it non-portable to any platform where `a` mode means "seek to the end before each operation".

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Actually, Padraic was probably right to use `w+` rather than `r+` here; he either missed the typo in my comment and just assumed that I wrote the right thing, or he already knew the right thing and didn't need to read my comment. :)

Comment: @abarnert nope, it was r+ then, after my comment changed to w+

Answer (score 1):

The print just prints the output of `str(file)`.

If you want to read the contents, open the file with `w+` for read-write, then seek to the beginning, and read the contents:

```
with open(filename, 'w+') as target
    print >> target, "something"
    ...
    target.seek(0)
    print(target.read())
```

Or close the file, and open it again for reading:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    print f.read()
```

Answer (score 1):

`print target` displays the [file object](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html). If you want to see the content that was written,

1. close the file `target.close()`. This will also flush all the unwritten buffered content
2. reopen the file in read mode `target = open(filename, 'r')`
3. Iterate over the file to print the content.

   ```
   with open(filename, 'r') as fin:
       for line in fin:
           print line
   ```